# Creating an int array with a non-const size

Tags: c++, constants

I'm currently making a plugin for a game and I've got the following problem:

I want to let the user choose the radius, but since C++ doesn't let me create an array with a variable size I can't get a custom radius.

This works fine

```
        const int numElements = 25;
    const int arrSize = numElements * 2 + 2;
    int vehs[arrSize];
    //0 index is the size of the array
    vehs[0] = numElements;
    int count = GET_PED_NEARBY_VEHICLES(PLAYER_PED_ID(), vehs);
```

but this dosen't:

```
    int radius = someOtherVariableForRadius * 2;
    const int numElements = radius;
    const int arrSize = numElements * 2 + 2;
    int vehs[arrSize];
    //0 index is the size of the array
    vehs[0] = numElements;
    int count = GET_PED_NEARBY_VEHICLES(PLAYER_PED_ID(), vehs);
```

Is there any possible way of modifing that const int without creating errors in

```
int vehs[arrSize];
```

?

Comment: Have you considered using `std::vector`?

Comment: I don't think it would work, definition of the GET_PED_NEARBY_VEHICLES function is:

[Image](http://i.imgur.com/88DBH5Z.png)

Comment: @Hx0 `std::vector` has the [`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) member function just for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array sizes must be compile-time constants in C++.

In your first version, `arrSize` is compile-time constant because its value can be calculated during compile-time.

In your second version, `arrSize` is not compile-time constant because its value can only be calculated at run-time (because it depends on user input).

The idiomatic way to solve this would be to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<int> vehs(arrSize);
//0 index is the size of the array
vehs[0] = numElements;
```

And to get the pointer to the underlying array, call [`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data):

```
int count = GET_PED_NEARBY_VEHICLES(PLAYER_PED_ID(), vehs.data());
```

Comment: That worked out, thanks! I didn't know that vectors could solve this problem(Almost never used them before, pretty new to c++)